# move items to the another listbox which is searched by textbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox, listbox, move

I am beginner at programming. I'm trying to build a form based app using visual basic according to a example in youtube.

In the form I cant move a item from `listbox1` to `listbox2` which was searched in `textbox2`

When I write the first item which is placed in first row of `listbox1` it moves item to `listbox2` but if I try with another item it cant move to listbox2.

I would be happy if someone can help me about this case.

Here are a picture of my form and the code I use :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

a Lot depends on what you are putting into the listboxes. If it is simple stuff like a, b, c, d etc it will add everything to listbox 2 as you have your code under text_changed event. Try and use a button when user stopped typing to search for the entire word.

Also add your text after the sc Call to your sc sub before the return statement as well -

```
Sub sc()
''Current code

''If Textbox2<text - remove, already called...
Listbox2.Items.Add(Listbox1.Text)
Listbox1.Items.Remove(Listbox1.SelectedIndex)
Return
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Andre, thanks for help . I put button for searching item in listbox1 and I add the codes end of Sub sc() that you brought to me.But the result is same.When ı write the first item at first row , the scripts allow first item to writing onto listbox2 but when I try for example second or third row item it doesnt write onto listbox 2